# Phpmyadmin not selecting correct vaues

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running this query in my database:

```
SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN profile ON posts.user_id = profile.user_id 
WHERE posts.user_id IN
  (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE class_name IN 
    (SELECT class_name FROM classroom WHERE created_by = '456'))
OR posts.user_id IN 
  (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE role = 'teacher' AND school_name = 'SK Taman Megah')
ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC;
```

This is my classroom table:

[image: Classroom table]

This is my users table:

[image]

This is my post table:

[image]

This is my profile table:

[image]

This is my output:

[image]

Expected output should have a total of 4 rows with post_id of (60,57,61,56) but only 2 was shown. Is there a mistake in the SQL query?

Comment: You have pasted pictures of your tables, but it would be much easier if you included them as text data and possibly an executing example on sqlfiddle.com so people trying to help have the resources available to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following one is what you are expecting:

```
SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN profile ON posts.user_id = profile.user_id where posts.user_id IN (select distinct user_id from users left join classroom on classroom.class_name = users.class_name where classroom.created_by='456' or (users.role='teacher' and users.school_name='SK Taman Megah') )
```

Comment: Yes it worked. So somehow sql does not work if there is a subquery in a subquery?